# Node js on virtual machine ignores requests from outside

Tags: node.js, express, debian, virtual-machine

this is the first time I use nodejs (and express), so I'm sorry if the question is stupid.

I installed nodejs and express on my debin virtual machine and created hello-world application. I run it like

DEBUG=myapp ./bin/www

Calling my application from virtual machine works just fine, but it ignores requests from outside workspace (windows). I thought it could be related to apache that I also have, so I stopped it, but it doesn't solve the issue. Please advice.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you making these requests from Windows to the guest VM? You have not given enough info. What ports are you binding to in your app?

Comment: just trying to open http://localhost:3000 in my browser, which fails all the time. when I'm trying to do curl http://localhost:3000 from vm -- it works pretty good. Also, when I run apache, http://localhost is available from windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And this is how I solved it.

1. Opened port 3000 in Firewall (not sure if this was required), see how to do this http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-port-windows-firewall
2. Added port forwarding in my vm settings in virtualbox. By default there were ports 80 and 22. So I added 3000 which was the solution.